# Propensity score matching without real treatment

Tags: propensity-scores

I need to evaluate the effect of self-employment status on the job-satisfaction. My data is a cross-section.

```
Occupatinal_status  Job_satisfaction  Male    Married
Self-Employed        1                Male    Yes
Paid-employment      5                Male    No
Paid-employment      3                Male    Yes
Paid-employment      4                Female  Yes
Paid-employment      2                Female  Yes
Self-Employed        1                Male    No
Self-Employed        4                Male    No
```

Here Self-emplyed is 1, Paid-employed is 0. The variable is a job description, i. e. it is not a real treatment. It is likewise educational level (PhD or not) etc. Is it correct to use "Ocupational_status" variable likewise treatment variable in propensity score matching?

Is any way to resolve this problem and provide correct evaluation?

Comment: I don't quite understand your situation. What do you mean that you have "occupation status", but that you don't know if someone is self-employed? Can you provide a small example dataset?

Comment: Why do you need propensity score? Logistic regression is good.

Comment: You can use propensity scores even for non-treatment covariates. Depending on your event per variable ratio (eg above 10), propensity scores might be unnecessary though.

Comment: If you want to interpret it as a causal effect you have to be willing to assume that everything you use in the construction of the propensity score is unaffected by the 'treatment' which, for example, may not be true for marital status - if sex, education and marital status are the only pre-treatment covariates you have observed, then the exchangeability assumption will also be extremely tenuous.